# Spring Boot 2 Maven project running on Intellij but not on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I've been trying to this without much success so any clues hinting to a solution would be appreciated. I'm not a Maven expert at all so this may be the principal issue.

I currently have a SpringBoot backend that is perfectly running if I run it from Intellij SpringBoot. But if I **mvn clean install** to create a war package to deploy in **Tomcat8.5** then I get a **404 error** for all routes I've tried.

This is the pom.xml for the parent directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>eu.sacs</groupId>
<artifactId>sacs-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>Parent</description>

<modules>
    <module>sacs-knowledge-extraction</module>
    <module>sacs-repository-oracle</module>
    <module>sacs-service</module>
    <module>sacs-webservice</module>
</modules>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3</maven>
</prerequisites>

<properties>
    <framework.version>0.0.0</framework.version>
    <java.version>1.10</java.version>
    <repo.path></repo.path>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Module dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.sacs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sacs-webservice</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.sacs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sacs-service</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.sacs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sacs-repository-oracle</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.sacs</groupId>
            <artifactId>sacs-knowledge-extraction</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Jena -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database - Oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Excel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sacs</id>
        <url>file://${repo.path}</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>sacs</id>
        <url>file://${repo.path}</url>
    </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <!-- <finalName>${warname}</finalName> -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.10</source>
                <target>1.10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this one is the one for the webservice (the other modules are compiled into jar for the webservice)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>eu.sacs</groupId>
    <artifactId>sacs-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>sacs-webservice</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>Rest API and Controller</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.sacs</groupId>
        <artifactId>sacs-service</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Finally here's the relevant part of the Tomcat log:

```
25-Oct-2018 12:58:15.012 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\sacs-webservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
25-Oct-2018 12:58:23.167 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
25-Oct-2018 12:58:23.636 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [216] milliseconds.
25-Oct-2018 12:58:23.677 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.34\webapps\sacs-webservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [8,665] ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally managed to figure it out basically by following [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).

Basically I had to extend my Main class with `SpringBootServletInitializer`, override `configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)` and finally and probably most important, add this **missing maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And then everything works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

There is no error during deployment of `sacs-webservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war` in your log. By default the WAR name is the context path after deployment so in your case an example URL will look like `http://localhost:8080/sacs-webservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT/index.html`.

When running from within IntelliJ the WAR file name is not part of the context path so an example URL will look like `http://localhost:8080/index.html`. This will further depend on the Run Configuration in IntelliJ, but it's generally true for `mvn clean package spring-boot:run` command.

Bottom line is, the URL is different since you chosen to use standalone Tomcat.

Comment: I already tried `http://localhost:8080/sacs-webservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT/backend_routes`. Same issue (the app doesn't have an index.html actually). Tried renaming the war to something more readable and even accessing the root access point through `localhost:8080/manager` to avoid weird spelling or something witout success.

In Intellij I'm not running tomcat but SpringBoot Configuration which I believe (but not totally sure) runs `mvn SpringBoot:run`.

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero try listing applications with `http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list`, do you see your WAR?

Comment: Yeah, that's totally working: `/sacs-webservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT:running:0:sacs-webservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT`

If I go to the manager interface and click in the loink to the app it redirects me to `localhost:8080//sacs-webservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT` which bis 404, that's ok, no `index.html` present there. But if I go to any route in the backend like, lets say `localhost:8080//sacs-webservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT/admin/getUsers` which in INtellij is returning a perfectly normal Json it just returns me a 404 and no error logged in `catalina.out`.

Comment: In case it helps, I just tried running `mvn spring-boot:run` and it's not able to deploy tomcat because it finds several errors (that I'm trying to solve right now). Some of this are related to something weird I saw before: If I use `jd-gui` to see the `war` file I see one of the packages empty (showing null in it in jd-gui when it's is not). But then when Tomcat explodes the `war` the classes in that package back so I didn't thought that would be a problem, specially since Tomcat didn't show any error while deploying it.

Comment: And finally fixed spring-boot:run which now runs smoothly but same behaviour in Tomcat.